# Package XBRL Fails to Download Schema

Tags: r, http-status-code-404, xbrl

The XBRL package cannot locate an existing XSD with the following:

```
url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/51143/000104746916010329/ibm-20151231.xml"
xbrl.vars <- xbrlDoAll(url, cache.dir = "XBRLcache", prefix.out = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
```

The error is:

```
Error in fileFromCache(file) : 
  Error in download.file(file, cached.file, method = "auto", quiet = !verbose) : 
  cannot download all files

In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(file, cached.file, method = "auto", quiet = !verbose) :
  URL 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/51143/000104746916010329/ibm-20151231.xsd': status was '404 Not Found'
```

The XSD exists however. I am running R 3.3.2 on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Have you tried eliminating access issues by downloading the xsd and placing it in a directory with any files it needs? Note: there are multiple imports in the xsd /xml uri references it's depending on.